# How to save a protege 4.3 project in .n3 file notation?

Tags: owl, protege, n3

I have a protege project and i have saved it in .owl file format and i want now to genrate a .n3 file from the same project. Is there a way out using Protege 4.3?

Comment: I haven't checked yet, but if there's an option to save as Turtle, use that.  Turtle (if I recall correctly) is a subset of N3, so if you save something as a Turtle, it's also a legal N3 file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. However, if you are using Protege to create the OWL file, chances are that you don't need specific features of N3 that are not part of Turtle.

Turtle is a [subset of N3](https://www.w3.org/TeamSubmission/n3/#subsets):

> Turtle is another subset, for only expressing RDF. It is like n3-rdf
>   below except that it does not have the path syntax.

So the answer is: save it as `Turtle syntax` and change the extension to `.n3`

Note: If by any chance you need to use named graphs (`TRIG`) you can manually edit the file and add the corresponding name like this:

```
//prefixes
:graphName {
    // ....
}
```